# How to allow user to change connectionString without compromising security?

Tags: .net, sql-server

There is app.config, but anybody can read it and easily log in to Database (in my case, SQL Server).
I need to deploy several programs that connect to same database server to different clients so I cannot re-build a program for each of them.

I'm using WPF and WindowsForms with SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option is to place connection string in your code and encrypt it. When a connection to server is needed, decrypt the connection string an use internally in your app. This helps you hide connection information from eyes of basic users, not advanced (hackers) who can decompile your binaries.

The second option is also the most reliable is to prevent clients from directly accessing DB. Instead, make some APIs on server and let clients invoke them. This way the connection is completely removed from your app and it gives you more freedom to scale your system. But it costs more.